# Bukkit title issue

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

In Minecraft, the plugin I've been making does a few things, including sending a title to a player on join. Often it will loop and send the title many times. The biggest one it's gotten to so far is over 100,000 times. I can't figure out where the problem is. There are no errors of any kind. Here is a bit of my code:

CLASS PLogin:

```
package me.photon.PLogin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class OnLogin implements Listener{
    private final main plugin;
public OnLogin(main plugin){
    this.plugin=plugin;
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
}
//Variables----------------------
private String name;
private Player target;
private String world="Spawn2.0";
//End Variables------------------
@EventHandler
private void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event){
    new BukkitRunnable(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if((event.getPlayer() instanceof Player)){
    target=event.getPlayer();
    name=event.getPlayer().getName();
    Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(),"sun "+target.getWorld().getName()+" sun");
    Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(),"title "+name+" title {text:'"+plugin.getConfig().getString("title")+"';color:"+plugin.getConfig().getString("titlecolor")+"}");
    Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(),"title "+name+" subtitle {text:'"+plugin.getConfig().getString("subtitle")+"';color:"+plugin.getConfig().getString("subcolor")+"}");
    if(target.getWorld().getName().equals(world)||target.getWorld().getName().equals("Skyblock")){
        GiveItems gi=new GiveItems(plugin);
        gi.main(target);
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<target.getInventory().getSize();i++){
            ItemStack ci=target.getInventory().getItem(i);
            GiveItems gi=new GiveItems(plugin);
            System.out.println(ci);
            if(ci.getAmount()>=1&&ci!=null&&(ci==gi.creative()||ci==gi.new_survival()||ci==gi.ninjas()||ci==gi.old_survival()||ci==gi.parkour()||ci==gi.prison()||ci==gi.skyblock()||ci==gi.dcreative()||ci==gi.dnew_survival()||ci==gi.dninjas()||ci==gi.dold_survival()||ci==gi.dparkour()||ci==gi.dprison()||ci==gi.dskyblock())){
                int amt=ci.getAmount();
                ci.setAmount(amt-=1);
                target.updateInventory();
                System.out.println("Deleted "+ci);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!target.hasPlayedBefore()){  
    plugin.getConfig().set("exempt."+name+".exempt", false);
    plugin.saveConfig();
    plugin.reloadConfig();
            }
            }
            if(plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("tp")){
                if(plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("exempt."+name+".exempt")==false){
                    b("tp","spawn");
                }
            }
            this.cancel();
        }
    }.runTaskLater(this.plugin, 20);

}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void a(String msg){
    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', msg));
}
private void b(String cmd1, String cmd2){
    Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), cmd1+name+cmd2);
}
public Player getTarget(){
    return target;
}
public String getWorld(){
    return world;
}
}
```

CLASS main:

```
package me.photon.PLogin

//imports

public final class main extends JavaPlugin{
@Override
public void onEnable(){
    this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    this.saveConfig();
    this.saveDefaultConfig();
    new OnLogin(this);
}
}
```

Sorry if I left anything out like variables.
Thanks in advance for your help,

Photon

P.S. To anyone looking for code examples, don't use this post! (some things may be missing) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not cancelling the BukkitRunnable after displaying the tile.
You should add `this.cancel();` After displaying the titles.

Comment: Will it stop everything past that? I have quite a bit of code I need to run past that. Sorry, don't know much about that.

Comment: It will only cancel the BukkitRunnable, everything in between `new BukkitRunnable` and `.runTaskLater(this.plugin, 20);`. I reccomend you to read this article from the Bukkit's wiki [Scheduler Programming](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming)

Comment: Thanks, I've read the tutorial before. I still have other code inside the runnable I need to be delayed, so should I put the    this.cancel() before the brackets?

Comment: Yes, put it at the end so that the runnable wont run again and execute your code again.

Comment: Alright, now it runs the title twice the amount of times as the last time.. maybe that's the same issue. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...

Comment: Well, you should post the rest of your runnable code maybe the problem is in another part.